# Arduino Leonardo keyboard cmd

Tags: keyboard, arduino

I want access cmd in Windows 7 when a button on the board is pressed using an Arduino as a keyboard:

```
const int buttonPin = 2;
const int ledPin =  13;
int buttonState = 0;
char ctrlKey = KEY_LEFT_GUI;

void setup() {
  // Initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  // Initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop(){
  // Read the state of the pushbutton value:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

    delay(1000);
    Keyboard.press(ctrlKey);
    Keyboard.press('r');        // This call runs
    Keyboard.println("cmd");    // But here it won't write "cmd"
    Keyboard.press('10');
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
    delay(1000);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
}
```

I also tried with the methods write(), print(), and press() for each letter individually, but it fails. Mostly it minimize all programs or invite all programs that are pinned in windows toolbar.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code presses <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, and then <kbd>Super</kbd> along with some null key. You need to release <kbd>Super</kbd> before attempting to fill the textbox, and you need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of that strange key once you've filled it.

Comment: Ahaaa, that's the point. About enter, i couldn't find arduino keyboard modifier for enter [link](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/KeyboardModifiers).

Comment: `'\n'`, or `"\n"` as (part of) a string.

Comment: I get problem with print() method in Keyboard class. I have `Keyboard.print("echo 0.0.0.0 websitename.com >> %WINDIR%\\system32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts"); ` and result is `echo 0.0.0.0 websitename.com :: %WINDIR%zszstem32zdriverszetczhosts` but i want to print `echo 0.0.0.0 websitename.com >> %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`